# weird gap between top of div and wrapper

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help with the weird gap between the "arrow wrapper 2" div and "about" div as i dont understand why its there and where it is coming from. As i need the arrow at the bottom of the "about" div but i cannot use absolute as that messes everything up. So i tried making a wrapper but it is not 100vh of the div, weirdly. Any help would be amazing!!

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans');
@import "compass/css3";
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        background: transparent;
        font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}


#main{
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background:#ED4C67;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
/* Typewriter */
.typewrite{
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none; 
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size:60px;
    display:block;
}

/* arrow */
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}

i {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
}

.bounce {
  -moz-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}
#about {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background: white;
    display:block;
    
}



.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}

.skull {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}

.about_para {
    display:block;
    color:#ED4C67;
    font-size:40px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {

}

.vertical-center {
    position: relative;
    top:50%;
    left: 0%;
    transform:translate(0%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform:translate(0%, -50%);
}

.arrow2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
}

#portfolio {
     width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background:#ED4C67;
    display:block;
    position:bottom;
}

.wrappert {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.arrow-wrapper {
position: relative; 
}

.arrow-wrapper-2 {
    position: relative;
    height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>JAKUB ORZEG-WYDRA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        <div id="main">

            <div class="wrappert">
                <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>
            <a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "Hi, Im Jakub Orzeg-Wydra.", "Im a web designer.", "and a Media Producer." ]'>
            
            </a>
            </h1>
                </div> </div>

            <div class="arrow-wrapper"><div class="arrow bounce"><A href="#about"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i></A></div></div>

        </div>
        
        <div id="about">

        <div class="vertical-center">
        <center><p class="about_para">I am a 15 year old from scotland who <br>
loves to code and produce media like <br>
videos. I also love sports and fitness.</p></center></div>
            <div class="arrow-wrapper-2"><div class="arrow2 bounce"><A href="#about"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-5x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:red;"></i></A></div></div>
        
        </div>
        
        <div id="portfolio">
        
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, in that section you have two element. The first one with the height of it's content and the second one with **100vh** and both are in-flow elements (as the first one is only set to `position:relative`) so if you do the total you have more than 100vh. That's why the arrow that belong to 100vh section is outside.

If we refer to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> **relative**
>
> The element is positioned according to **the normal flow of the**
>   **document**, and then offset relative to itself based on the values of
>   top, right, bottom, and left. **The offset does not affect the position**
>   **of any other elements**; thus, **the space given** for the element in the
>   page layout **is the same** as if position were static.

To fix this you need to use absolute position with the first element (remove it from the flow so no more height considered) and make its parent relative position.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans');
@import "compass/css3";
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ED4C67;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}


/* Typewriter */

.typewrite {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  display: block;
}


/* arrow */

@-moz-keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80%,
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80%,
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}

i {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
}

.bounce {
  -moz-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}

#about {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  position:relative;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}

.skull {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.about_para {
  display: block;
  color: #ED4C67;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align:center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {}

.vertical-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

.arrow2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
}

#portfolio {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ED4C67;
  display: block;
  position: bottom;
}

.wrappert {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.arrow-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.arrow-wrapper-2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JAKUB ORZEG-WYDRA</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <div id="main">

    <div class="wrappert">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>
          <a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "Hi, Im Jakub Orzeg-Wydra.", "Im a web designer.", "and a Media Producer." ]'>

          </a>
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="arrow-wrapper">
      <div class="arrow bounce">
        <A href="#about"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i></A>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="about">

    <div class="vertical-center">
        <p class="about_para">I am a 15 year old from scotland who <br> loves to code and produce media like <br> videos. I also love sports and fitness.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow-wrapper-2">
      <div class="arrow2 bounce">
        <A href="#about"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-5x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:red;"></i></A>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="portfolio">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```